# How to change the default color palette for charts in flutter?

Tags: flutter, charts

I use charts_flutter to create charts. I know how to change the color, but I like to change the color palette. The default palette seems to be "blue".
For example in a pie chart, charts_flutter uses different shades of blue. I like to use deeporange as the default palette for all kind of charts.
Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is bit old, but I just had the same problem and found a solution.

```
    int numberOfColorsYouWant = 3;
    ...
    colorFn: (_, index){
      return charts.MaterialPalette.green.makeShades(numberOfColorsYouWant)[index];
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

Not currently using it but just looked rapidly at the code and saw this:

```
colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
fillColorFn: (_, __) =>
        charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault.lighter,
```

maybe you can change them changing this parameter.

This is the url where I found them : https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/stacked_fill_color

Comment: The colorFn: (_, __) change the color for all series in one color (for example blue). When I use this parameter I get a complete blue pie chart. I like to change the complete palette. So flutter will use different shades of orange.
So somewhere I must have the possibility to change the parameter from charts.MaterialPalette.blue to charts.MaterialPalette.deeporange (without shadeDefault)

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can set your custom color like this

```
 charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.deepPurple)
```

or

```
 charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff4EB200))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want different colors instead of shades you can use:

```
var palettes = charts.MaterialPalette.getOrderedPalettes(<number of palettes>);

var seriesColor = palettes.elementAt(i).shadeDefault;
```

Comment: would you provide the full code. i don't get (<number of palettes>) part

Comment: I got the reference  from here :https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog/blob/master/lib/routes/charts_pie_chart_ex.dart